# how to make my python code to run faster with Concurrent Futures library

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.4, mysql-python, concurrent.futures

This block of code here, fetches records from a mysql table with over 100k distinguished by unique ips. Then it takes set of ips in batch and processes on each of them.

The Problem that I face here is speed of execution and time. I tried running my script with ThreadPoolExecutor but it takes 10 hours to run over 100k records. So, to speed up I tried using ProcessPoolExecutor but it takes same amount of time.

Please suggest as what needs to be done to increase the execution speed of my script.

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(1, '/var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/Yogesh/pylib')
import argparse
import datetime
import sqlalchemy
import pymysql
import time
import concurrent.futures
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

def get_remaining_details(db_engine, ip, device):
    '''fetches model,network,region and size details for a particular device'''
    try:
        results = db_engine.execute("""select model,network,region_num,(select size from SSD_size where model=a.model)
            from
                SSD_fail_predictor a
            where
                inet_ntoa(machine_ip)='{0}' and device='{1}'""".
                                         format(ip, device)).fetchone()

    except Exception as exception:
        sys.stderr.write("FAILED to get details from {0} with {} : {1}".format(
            str(ip), str(device), str(exception)))
        sys.exit(1)

    return results

def insert_data(db_engine, adata, ip, device):
    ''' To insert the data passed into mysql'''
    try:
        results = db_engine.execute ("insert into ssd_dwpd values ('{0}','{1}',{days},{data_writes_gb},'{start_date}',{samples},{wpd_in_gb},'{model}',{size},{dwpd},'{network}',{region_num})".format(ip,device,**adata))
    except Exception as exception:
        sys.stderr.write("FAILED to insert data {0} into ssd_dwpd table: {1}".format(str(adata),str(exception)))
        sys.exit(1)
    return 1

def analyse_data(db_engine, ip, device):
    ''' How do we find drivers that have been replaced ?
    first, we sort the values of all the devices in descending order
    second, we create a pair of value using zip function which takes two adjacent values from sorted list
    third, we take the first value from the list where the differnce is negative
    so cutoff-1 is the highest index, after which is the replaced data'''

    mod, net, reg, size = ('','',0,0)
    details = get_remaining_details(db_engine,ip, device)
    if (details == None):
        with open("Void_SSD_Fail_Predictor.txt", 'a') as file1:
            file1.write(ip + " : " + device + "\n")
        return 1
    else:
        mod, net, reg, size = details

    if size == None:
        with open("Void_SSD_size.txt", 'a') as file2:
            file2.write(ip + " : " + mod + "\n")
        return 1

    try:
        attribute = []

        results = db_engine.execute(
            "select distinct attribute from lba_written where machineip='{0}' and device='{1}' order by time_stamp".format(str(ip), str(device)))
        for x in results:
            attribute.append(x[0])

        where_clause = ''

        if len(attribute) == 1:
            where_clause = "machineip='{0}' and device='{1}' and value > 0 order by time_stamp".format(str(ip), str(device))
        else:
            attribute = attribute[-1]
            where_clause = "machineip='{0}' and device='{1}' and attribute = '{2}' and value > 0 order by time_stamp".format(str(ip), str(device), attribute)

        results = db_engine.execute(
            "select (max(value)-min(value)) Value,count(1) as Sample,((max(time_stamp) - min(time_stamp)) / 86400) days,FROM_UNIXTIME(min(time_stamp)) start_day from lba_written where {wc}".format(wc=where_clause))

        value,samples,days,start_date = results.fetchone()

        if samples == 0:
            with open("nullip.txt", 'a') as f:
                f.write("IP: {0} with device: {1} has no samples with values > 0\n".format(ip, device))
            return 1

        if days > 1.0:
            days = float(round(days,2)) 
        else: 
            days = 1

        if attribute == 'Host_Writes_32MiB':
            data_writes_gb = round((value * 32) / 1024, 2)
        else:
            data_writes_gb = round((value * 512) / 1073741824, 2)

        wpd_in_gb = round(data_writes_gb / days, 2)
        dwpd = round(wpd_in_gb / size, 2)

    except Exception as exception:
        sys.stderr.write("For IP {0} Something is not correct here: {1}".format(
            str(ip), str(exception)))
        sys.exit(1)

    return {
        'data_writes_gb': data_writes_gb,
        'days': days,
        'network': net,
        'start_date': start_date,
        'samples': samples,
        'wpd_in_gb': wpd_in_gb,
        'model': mod,
        'region_num': reg,
        'size': size,
        'dwpd': dwpd,
    }

def get_devices_for_ip(db_engine, ip):
    """Fetches unique device for the passed ip"""
    devices = []
    try:
        results = db_engine.execute(
            "select distinct device from lba_written where machineip='{}'".format(str(ip)))
        for row in results.fetchall():
            devices.append(row[0])

    except Exception as exception:
        ## Ideally script should never come here ##
        sys.stderr.write("FAILED to get devices for {0} : {1}".format(
            str(ip), str(exception)))
        sys.exit(1)

    return devices

def process_ips(ip):
    """ Process IPs
    Input:
            IP address of the device
    Output:
            If updated 1 else 0
    """

    db_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mysql+pymysql://root:hdfs@xxx.xx.xx.xxx/hardware_perf")
    devices = get_devices_for_ip(db_engine,ip)
    for device in devices:
        analysed_data = analyse_data(db_engine,ip, device)
        #self.printv("Analysed data: {}".format(analysed_data))
        if (isinstance(analysed_data, dict) == True):
            op = insert_data(db_engine,
                             analysed_data, ip, device)
        elif (analysed_data == 1):
            op = 1
        else:
            op = 0
    db_engine.dispose()
    return op

def batcher(ips,seg_size):
    for x in range(0, len(ips), seg_size):
        yield ips[x:x + seg_size]

def printv(args, message):
    """ Print verbose message
            Print message only if VEBOSE is true
    Input:
                    message (str): string with message
            """
    if args.verbose:
        print(str(message))

def get_ips_from_db(args):
    '''Fetches distinct machine ips from db'''

    db_engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
        "mysql+pymysql://root:hdfs@xxx.xx.xx.xxx/hardware_perf")
    ips = []

    if args.limit:
        sql = "select distinct machineip from lba_written limit {}".format(
            int(args.limit))
    else:
        sql = "select distinct machineip from lba_written"
    try:
        results = db_engine.execute(sql)
        for ip in results.fetchall():
            ips.append(ip[0])

        if not ips:
            printv(args,"Got no device from lba_written table")
            sys.exit(1)

    except Exception as exception:
        sys.stderr.write(
            "FAILED to get IPs from db : {}".format(str(exception)))
        sys.exit(1)

    db_engine.dispose()
    printv(args, "Number of Distinct IPs got : {}".format(len(ips)))
    printv(args, "IPs are : {}".format(str(ips)))

    return ips

def arg_parser():

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Calculate dwpd for SSD")

    parser.add_argument(
        '--host',
        required=True,
        help='host name of mysql server'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-u',
        '--user',
        required=True,
        help='Username for login mysql server'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-p',
        '--password',
        help='password for login mysql'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '--db',
        required=True,
        help='database name in mysql'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-l',
        '--limit',
        type=int,
        help="limit to restrict number of IP's to be processed"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-v',
        '--verbose',
        default=0,
        help='Verbose mode'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-bs',
        '--batch_size',
        type=int,
        default=50,
        help='Number of records to process in each batch'
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        '-t',
        '--threads',
        type=int,
        default = 8,
        help='Number of threads'
    )

    return parser.parse_args()

def main():
    args = arg_parser()          
    ips = get_ips_from_db(args)

    for ips_batch in batcher(ips,args.batch_size):
        with ProcessPoolExecutor (max_workers=args.threads) as executor:
            try:
                results = executor.map(process_ips, ips_batch)
            except Exception as ex:
                print ("timeout: {}".format(ex))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print ("Finished")
```

Comment: So...you have a hadoop environment but you're not using distributed execution to massively parallelise this? Why not just use pyspark to do whatever you're doing?

Comment: @user202729  Earlier I did entire computation in python but now I moved some computation in mysql but still I dont find any considerable improvement in the speed

Comment: @Marcin We haven't setup Spark yet but yeah if I do not find any solution then I will definitely try that approach. Thanks!!

Comment: If it's possible in sql, it's possible in Pandas or Dask. Vector-based operators are faster than loops

Comment: Also, you're hitting the database a lot (multiple times per IP address). It's entirely possible that MySQL is the bottleneck here. You are likely to see better throughput if you do either one large fetch of all the data (possibly with processing by MySQL) or one fetch per batch.